# how do I Mock endpoints with blueprint in camel?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm writing an application using camel for deployment (eventually) in a fuse container.  The nature of the project requires that I mix and match Java and XML DSL.

I'm having trouble getting the mock framework to work properly with blueprint.

Here's my unit test, based completely on the example [here](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html).

```
public class MockNotWorking extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {

   @Test
   public void testAdvisedMockEndpointsWithPattern() throws Exception {

    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            mockEndpoints("log*");
        }
    });

    getMockEndpoint("mock:log:foo").expectedBodiesReceived("Bye World");
    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedBodiesReceived("Bye World");

    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello World");

    // additional test to ensure correct endpoints in registry
    assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("direct:start"));
    assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("log:foo"));
    assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:result"));
    // only the log:foo endpoint was mocked
    assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:log:foo"));
    assertNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:direct:start"));
    assertNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:direct:foo"));

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

   }


  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
              from("direct:start").to("direct:foo").to("log:foo").to("mock:result");

            from("direct:foo").transform(constant("Bye World"));
        }
    };
  }

  protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
    return "OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml";
  }
}
```

I have copied verbatim the example [here](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html), and modified it very slightly so we extend `CamelBlueprintTestSupport` instead of `CamelTestSupport`.  This requires over-riding `getBlueprintDescriptor` to point to my blueprint xml, in which I have defined one very basic (and completely irrelevant to the test) route:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

<camelContext id="validationRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >

    <route id="validation">
        <from uri="direct:validation" />
        <log message="validating..." />
    </route>
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

The test fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://log:foo Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
```

So this means the message did not reach the mock endpoint.  Change `CamelBlueprintTestSupport` for `CamelTestSupport` and it works.

So how do I get mocks like this working correctly with blueprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use blueprint, it imports all the routes you have defined in the blueprint xml file(s), and adds them to the `CamelContext`.

The reason this breaks things is that the `context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0)` no longer refers to the only route - there are now more than one.  So when you add the `AdviceWithRouteBuilder`, it could be added to the wrong route.

The following code fixes the problem (and will work for non-blueprint tests too):

```
List<RouteDefinition> routes = context.getRouteDefinitions();
    for (int i=0;  i<routes.size(); i++)    {
        context.getRouteDefinitions().get(i).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // mock all endpoints
                mockEndpoints("log*");
            }
        });
    }
```

======update======

A better way of doing this is rather than mocking all routes, find our specific route by id and then apply the advice.  This means first setting the route id:

```
 from("direct:start").routeId("start").to("direct:foo").to("log:foo").to("mock:result");
```

And then looking up the route by id and calling `adviceWith` as before:

```
context.getRouteDefinition("start").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // mock log endpoints
            mockEndpoints("log*");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on what version of Camel you are using, some methods doesn't work as expected. Its improved a lot better after 2.12 if I remember right. (2.15 is way better)

After all my encounters with Camel unit testing, I ended up documenting all stuffs here:

http://bushorn.com/unit-testing-apache-camel/

http://bushorn.com/camel-unit-testing-using-mock-endpoint/

By the way, instead of this "mockEndpoints("log*");", I would do this:

weaveByToString(".*direct:foo*.").after().to("mock:log"); (This sounds weird, I know ;) )

or if you can set an endpoint id

weaveById("endpoint-id-of-direct-foo").after().to("mock:log");

or

weaveAddLast().to("mock:log");